# I need help on displaying multiple text boxes for C#?

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to make a mailing label program using WinForms where you enter your name, state, city, etc. and it click on a button and it display all the text you entered in each box and displays it on one label. I am close but when i run my program, there is no space between the words. Here is my code:

```
namespace Mail_Label_Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = txtFirst.Text + txtLast.Text;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This closes the program.
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This clears all textbox forms.
            txtFirst.Text = string.Empty;
            txtLast.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCity.Text = string.Empty;
            txtStreet.Text = string.Empty;
            txtState.Text = string.Empty;
            txtZip.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace this:

```
lblMessage.Text = txtFirst.Text + txtLast.Text;
```

With this:

```
lblMessage.Text = txtFirst.Text + " " + txtLast.Text;
```

If someone enters leading/trailing blanks you might like this:

```
lblMessage.Text = trim(txtFirst.Text) + " " + (txtLast.Text);
```

Comment: it worked thanks. so for the city and state, can i keep adding the + and use + " " + txtCity.Text? I am trying to make it so it looks like a mailing label? You know how the name is on top, street is in the middle of the form, and the city, state, and zip is on bottom of form. How do i do that?

Comment: I assume that the city/state/zip go into a different field. Create a newline by adding  `System.Environment.NewLine` to your string.

Comment: I am a noob sorry. Where is the string?

Comment: lblMessage.Text is the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me out big time.

Answer (score 0):

```
lblMessage.Text = txtFirst.Text + " " +  txtLast.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lblMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text);
```

you can add further text like

```
lblMessage.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}...", txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text, text2, text3...);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't add a space between them when you concatenated the string. You can use:

```
lblMessage.Text = String.Join(" ", txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text);
```

The same `Join` method can be used for any number of fields:

```
String.Join(" ", txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text, txtCity.Text);
```

Alternatively, you can use `String.Format`:

```
string.Format("Name: {0} {1}, Address: {2}", txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text, txtCity.Text);
```